# What is an intuitive description of posterior distribution convergence?

Tags: bayesian, posterior

I understand posterior distribution convergence to be something akin to: the point at which additional sampling wouldn't substantially change the nature (i.e., mean and variance) of the posterior distribution. Is that accurate?

Comment: Are you referring to MCMC here? If you get stuck in a local mode that you can't escape, additional sampling might not change what you get but that  doesn't mean you have convergence to the correct posterior. (If you instead mean some form of independent sampling from a joint posterior, that wouldn't be an issue)

Comment: Would you mind clarifying "some form of independent sampling from a joint posterior"?

Comment: For a simple example, simulating independent iterates from a joint posterior by accept-reject (which may work well enough for some low-dimensional problems, for example). By contrast MCMC is dependent and only generates from the stationary distribution asymptotically --  what "convergence" is used to mean for that case is different.from if it was used in the first case.

Comment: Or do you mean convergence with the number of observations, which refers to consistency and more precise results like the Bernstein-von Mises theorems..?